# Dafault Value in Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Is it possible to change the default value of "current Date" from US date and time to UK date and time?

I am trying to do this for a triggered send within the Exact Target platform, am not sure if this is possible or not. I want to send out a follow up email 7 days after they have received the real-time email.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In ExactTarget in the top right hand corner, if you mouse over your name, you should see **Administration** in the drop down menu. Select **Administration**, then select **Edit**. Under **General Settings**, you should be able to select a new time zone.

The time zone change should affect the UI, standard reports, and extracts so your triggered send should follow the updated time zone that is now reflected in the UI.

[ET link for timezones and date format settings](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/admin/timezone_and_date_format_settings/)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no you can't change the default value for a date field to a timezone other than CST". However, when your evaluating this date in a filter or query activity for your seven day followup email, you're also evaluating against the current time in CST. This takes a little getting your head around, but try being in Australia where most of our day is in a different day to CST.

Changing your timezone does indeed change the settings for scheduling and for tracking reports etc. It doesn't change the actual data that's stored in the database, which is always CST.